# Error: Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_create]

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, woocommerce

I tried to post a product using woocommerce rest API using Laravel, in basic authentication i'm using data from env (store url, consumer key, consumer secret). But i want it dynamic, so i get that 3 elements (store url, consumer key, consumer secret) from database. Fyi, i am make some form to post store url, consumer key, consumer secret into database. What i want to ask is when i use data from env for authentication post product there's no problem, but when i use data from database its show error like this: Error: Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_create]. Anyone have a solution? i'm so confused, sorry for my bad english.

Screenshots:
[this is when i use 3 points for authenticate from env, no problem in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFmwO.png)
[when i use 3 points for authenticate with method like this (get from database), it will show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N273B.png)
[error like this if i use method in pict number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuJE3.png)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this **after** the WordPress 5.6 updadte, I was able to fix this with 1 small file change, then a visit to the *WordPress Admin Dashboard*...

#### File change

Changed the WordPress section of `.htaccess` **from**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

...to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Add Basic Auth
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    
    # Add HTTP Auth
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # Default WordPress stuff...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### WordPress Admin

1. Log in to the WordPress Dashboard as an Admin or Super Admin
2. Navigate to *Users* => *All Users*
3. Select the user created for the WooCommerce REST API
4. Scrolled to the new *Application Passwords* section
5. Set up a new application
6. Saved the user

...then

1. Navigate to *WooCommerce* => *Settings* => *Advanced*
2. Click on the *REST API* option
3. Click the credentials that were set for the WooCommerce API
4. Made a minor update to the name (to force an update)
5. Saved

While I'm not sure of the impact of re-saving the REST API cred's, the WooCommerce API started working correctly **immediately** afterwards :-)

##### Edit:

An additional change **may** need to be made, for some servers, too...

**From:**

```
$wooClient = new Automattic\WooCommerce\Client(
    "https://www.example.com",
    getenv("WOO_CLIENT_KEY"),
    getenv("WOO_CLEINT_SECRET"),
    [
        "version" => "wc/v3",
        "verify_ssl" => (getenv("WP_ENV") == "development" ? false : true)
    ]
);
```

**To:**

```
$wooClient = new Automattic\WooCommerce\Client(
    "https://www.example.com",
    getenv("WOO_CLIENT_KEY"),
    getenv("WOO_CLEINT_SECRET"),
    [
        "version" => "wc/v3",
        "verify_ssl" => (getenv("WP_ENV") == "development" ? false : true),
        "wp_api" => true,
        "query_string_auth" => true
    ]
);
```

##### Sources:

*Basic Auth Header Missing* Github issue:
https://github.com/WordPress/application-passwords/wiki/Basic-Authorization-Header----Missing

WordPress 5.6 *Application Passwords* update:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/

*Example for servers that not properly parse the Authorization header* note on WooCommerce's documentation
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#authentication-over-https

Comment: Hi after doing all this, i am still getting rest_cannot_create_application_passwords this error. i am trying to create application password through api call